# Extracting floating point numbers in a string using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list of strings

```
List = ['A = -25.47 dBm' , 'B = -47.35 dBm' , 'A = -26.54 dBm' , 'B = -32.35 dBm', 'A = 27.95 dBm' , 'B = -64.11 dBm' , 'A = -45.11 dBm' , 'B = -18.67 dBm']
```

I want to extract the values of A make a list of that, values of B and make a list of that

I have tried the following

```
#First I joined the data into a string
S = ' '.join(List)
re.findall(r"A =  ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+) dBm" , S)
```

which doesn't seem to work

Expected Result

```
A_list = [-25.47,-26.54, 27.95,-45.11] 
B_list = [-47.35,-32.35,-64.11,-18.67]
```

Comment: Your regex has two spaces after `=` but the input has only one space after `=`.

Comment: thanks , i am feeling so dumb now lol!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re` and `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import re, collections
l = ['A = -25.47 dBm' , 'B = -47.35 dBm' , 'A = -26.54 dBm' , 'B = -32.35 dBm', 'A = 27.95 dBm' , 'B = -64.11 dBm' , 'A = -45.11 dBm' , 'B = -18.67 dBm']
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
for i in l:
  a, b = re.findall('^\w+|[\-\d\.]+', i)
  d[a].append(float(b))

A_list, B_list = d['A'], d['B']
```

Output:

```
[-25.47, -26.54, 27.95, -45.11]
[-47.35, -32.35, -64.11, -18.67]
```

Comment: isn't there a way to do in this format re.findall(r"A =  ([-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+) dBm" , S)

Comment: @dd24 That will work to extract the float value, but you will need to use at least an `S.split(' =')[0]` or another `re.findall` to find the letter.